# weighted CDF formula always returns 1

Tags: matlab, math, image-processing, cdf, image-enhancement

I am reading [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0030402619301718?via%3Dihub) for enhancing image quality.
my problem is that when I am calculating weighted CDF, I always get 1 as output.
here is the sequence of formulas:

[image: formula 1]

which `gamma` is defined like this:

[image]

which `Cw` is the weighted CDF:
[image]
[image]
**which I think my main problem would be here.**

but to be more clear I will add the rest of the formulas too.
corresponding Weighted Histogram Distribution function is:
[image]
and `Alpha=C(i)` which:
[image]
[image]
which `h_c(i)` is clipped histogram , and `M` is the total intensity levels ( which I'm not sure what is the `M`, I assumed since `sum of Pi` should be `1` so it must be `sum of the hc_i` )
and this is how it is clipping the histogram  :

[image]

and the clipping limit is calculated with this formula:

[image]

here is my code:

```
sample_img = imread('my image path');
sample_img = im2double(sample_img);
L = 256 % The magnitude of each and every color channel is confined within the range [0 , L-1]
redChannel = sample_img(:,:,1);
greenChannel = sample_img(:,:,2);
blueChannel = sample_img(:,:,3);
max_blue = max(max(blueChannel));
max_green = max(max(greenChannel));
max_red = max(max(redChannel));

min_blue = min(min(blueChannel));
min_green = min(min(greenChannel));
min_red = min(min(redChannel));

bn = blueChannel - min_blue;
rn = redChannel - min_red;
gn = greenChannel - min_green;

max_bn = max(max(bn));
max_rn = max(max(rn));
max_gn = max(max(gn));

b_stretched = bn/max_bn;
r_stretched = rn/max_rn;
g_stretched = gn/max_gn; 


% Recombine separate color channels into an RGB image.
rgb_stretched_Image = cat(3, r_stretched, g_stretched, b_stretched);

% Convert RGB to HSI
hsi_image = rgb2hsi(rgb_stretched_Image);

intensity = hsi_image(:, :, 3);
figure()
[counts , binLocations] = imhist(intensity);
imhist(intensity);

hist = counts;
% the clipping limit is computed based on the mean value of the
Tc = mean(hist);

% histogram clipping 
length_hist = length(hist);
clipped_hist = zeros(1,length_hist);
for hist_id = 1:length_hist
    if hist(hist_id)<Tc
        disp('<Tc')
        disp(hist(hist_id));
        clipped_hist(hist_id) = hist(hist_id);
        continue
    end
    disp('>Tc')
    clipped_hist(hist_id) = Tc;
end

% the corresponding PDF (p(i))
% this is where I just used sum(clipped_hist) instead of M
Pi = clipped_hist / sum(clipped_hist);

%CDF
Ci = sum(Pi(1:L));
Alpha = Ci;

%Weighted Histogram Distribution function 
Pmin = min(Pi);
Pmax = max(Pi);

Pwi = Pmax * power((Pi-Pmin)/(Pmax-Pmin),Alpha);

%weighted PDF sum 
intensity_max = max(max(intensity*L)); 
Sum_Pwi = sum(Pwi(1:intensity_max));

% weighted CDF
Cwi = sum(Pwi(1:intensity_max)/Sum_Pwi);

%gamma
gamma = 1 - Cwi;

%Transformed pixel intensity 
tpi = round(power(intensity/intensity_max,gamma));
```

since as I said the CDF output is always 1 , the enhanced image is always a white image. and as I see this formula, it must always have 1 as it's output. Am I missing something here ?
and am I right with the `M` value ?

Comment: `gamma` is not one value, for each intensity there is a value of gamma, which is the inverse of the weighed CDF `1 - C_w(i)` for that specific intensity `i` and `I(u,v)`, better they use another notion like `gamma(i)`, also `I_max` is not 255, for each `i` there is corresponding `I_max`, the paper is a complete mess, I don't know how did they publish it!

Comment: @Bilal thank you. so you mean I must calculate `I_max` and `C_w` and `gamma` in a for loop? but how to compute `I_max` for each `i` ?

Comment: `I_max = i` for each value of `I_max = i` you will accumulate the PDF(Probability Density Function) to get the CDF corresponding to that `i`